# Use htaccess to restrict by IP, but unrestrict one directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to restrict access to a domain to one IP address, but allow anyone to access one directory within that domain. So I have this in my .htaccess (in web root):

```
<RequireAll>
    Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx
</RequireAll>
```

which is working great to restrict access, but then when I want to allow unrestricted access to /folder within the root, so I tried:

```
<Directory "/home/*/public_html/folder">
 Allow from All
 Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

but then I get a 500 error. So how would I accomplish this? And why the 500?

Also, for reference, here's the rest of the htaccess, which routes all requests to the index.php

```
# Remove ".php" from path
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `<Directory>` in `.htaccess`, that will be why you're getting a 500 (BTW you should be using your server logs to see the real error msgs, you're working blind without them). AFAIK you need to move the `Allow ...` section to a second  `.htaccess`, in your public dir.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/46575/apache-authentication-allow-public-access-to-a-subdirectory

Comment: You can also use `SetEnvIf` to set a custom enviroment variable based on whether the requested URL path includes your specific directory, and then use `Satisfy any` in combination with `Allow from env=your_custom_var_name`